# Toggle Button Image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have multiple of buttons.

They all load in the viewDidLoad. I want it so once one button has been pressed, it changes to the other image.

So Img1 loads via the viewDidload, then once it's been pressed, it goes to Img2

This is my current code which i have tried:

In the viewdidload:

```
btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(367, 117, 97, 25)];
[btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(playSound:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];
```

In the ibaction (which i tried, but im guessing)

```
-(IBAction)ButtonAction
{

    if (btn1==0)
    {
        btn1=1;
        [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
    {
        [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn1=0;

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are hooking up your `UIButton` to the proper selector. Also, I would use an `@property` or a global / instance variable to track which image is currently in the `UIButton`. Here's some code that should do the trick:

```
//... in @interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *btn1ImageName;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // ...

  self.btn1ImageName = @"img1.png";
  btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(367, 117, 97, 25)];
  [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.btn1ImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view addSubview:btn1];
}

- (void)toggleImage:(UIButton *)btn1 {
  self.btn1ImageName = ([self.btn1ImageName isEqualToString:@"img1.png"]) ? @"img2.png" : @"img1.png";
  [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.btn1ImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (btn1==0)
```

I don't get that part.

One easy solution would be to have two different images for a selected and un-selected state.

btn1.selected = YES, will automatically choose the selected button image.
btn1.selected = NO, will automaticall choose the un-selected button image.